# data-bind click event does not work on chrome for svg under div

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, knockout.js, onclick

I am working with knockout.js and this is my code -

```
<div data-bind = "event:{click: clickHandler}">
    <svg ...>
        <polygon ... > </polygon>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Clicking on svg does not work on chrome, I have to click outside svg on div, for it to work on chroms. For some reason, the click event isn't fired in chrome, but it works fine in IE 11 and Edge browsers.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You already tried to add the data-bind value between quotes? like: data-bind="event:..." ?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for the confusion. Updated code above.

Comment: I made some tests on jsfiddle and nothing is wrong with your code. Take a look on the JS console of chrome for some error, and make sure that the knockout.js lib is declarated on the file, also, that ko.applyBindings(); is called on the end of the code (or on the .ready event)

Comment: here a sample on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MarcelKohls/tmjmydmy/

Comment: Thanks Marcel, helped me narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the div containing above div, needed  pointer-events : none property

```
<div style ="pointer-events: none">
   <div data-bind = "event:{click: clickHandler}">
      <svg ...>
        <polygon ... > </polygon>
      </svg>
   </div>
<div>
```